# $("this").attr("name") through undefined

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="" id="onepagecheckout_orderform">
<input type="text" id="billing:firstname" name="billing[firstname]" value="" title="First Name" class="t1 required-entry"/>
<input type="text" id="billing:lastname" name="billing[lastname]" value="" title="Last Name" class="t1 required-entry"/>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="" name="shipping[clone]" id="shippingClone" title="Clone"/>
<label for="shippingClone">Ship to same address</label>
```

And jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function cloneMe() {
        $("#onepagecheckout_orderform input:text").each(function () {
            alert($('this').attr("name"));
        });
        return false;
    };
    $('#shippingClone').on('click', function () {
        cloneMe();
    });
});
```

The jsfiddle link is: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/velmurugansp/Ljhpb/)

When I click check box, it should show name of all input:type. But it says "undefined".

Please help me out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this
this with out ""

```
alert($(this).attr("name"));
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
alert($(this).attr("name"));
```

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) without single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Well the best way is to just use the node property name, no need to use jquery at all here:

```
alert(this.name);
```

Comment: Thanks Roasted.
But I don't understand where I have to use ("this") and (this)

Comment: $(this) is just the element 'this' wrapped in a jquery object. That means you add jquery functionalities to the element 'this'. In your specific case, its just useless.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#onepagecheckout_orderform input:text").each(function() {
                        console.log($(this));
                        alert($(this).attr('name'));
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$` function can take a number of different arguments. If you give it a DOM object (like `this`) then it will wrap it with a `jQuery` object.

If you pass it a string (which doesn't look like a piece of HTML) then it will treat it as a selector, search the DOM for matching elements, and wrap a `jQuery` object around them.

You are passing it a string, so it will find all the `<this>` elements (which there aren't any of, and can't be in an HTML document).

You want to pass it `this`, not `'this'`.